# Does the shape of the Higgs mexican hat depend on the temperature of the universe?

Tags: cosmology, temperature, field-theory, standard-model, higgs

I am reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.05760) and i wonder if it is mainstream. Does the VeV of the Higgs field evolve with time? What about the mass given to the fermions?

Answer (score 3):

Yes and yes to your first two questions.

Fermions are massless at sufficiently high temperature when the VEV is zero and the symmetry unbroken. They acquire mass when the universe expands and cools, the VEV becomes nonzero, and the symmetry breaks.

Comment: i have in mind a problem about the spontaneous symmetry breaking. it is like decoherence. the density matrix is never strictly diagonal. Here the temperature is low but not null. at which temperature does   the VeV appear?

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/153743/temperature-of-electroweak-phase-transition